# Error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, arrays, division, operands

I've seen several questions like this one but none of them solve my issue in the correct way. Meaning the way that it is answered is either not working or makes no sense to me. I'll give you the code thats giving me fits and the error it's giving.

```
Error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Is the error and the code is:

```
#Define iteration#
iteration=0;
iterationNum=0;

#Define encryption#
def encrypt(num,iteration):
    num=cos(num/(iteration+1));

def runEncrypt(array,iterationNum):
    for j in range(iterationNum):
        for i in range (len(array)):
            array[i]=encrypt(array[i],j);

#Internal test area#
array1=[1,2,3,4,5];
encryptedArray=runEncrypt(array1,4);
print(encryptedArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `encrypt` function does not have a `return` statement, so its return value will be `None` (the default return value for Python functions without a `return` statement) and so `None` will be assigned to every element of `array` in the first iteration of the outer loop in `runEncrypt()`. This means that, in the second and later iterations of the outer loop, `encrypt()` will be called with `(None, j)` as its arguments, and the error will be raised because the program tries to divide `None` by an integer, which is undefined.

To resolve this, simply redefine `encrypt` as follows:

```
def encrypt(num, iteration):
    return cos(num / (iteration + 1))
```